# C Pass the Parent-Thread ID

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, arguments, pthreads

how do I pass the parent ID and print it out in second printf()??

**Example first line:**

I am 1 and and I have 4 child(dren) my parents ???
I am 2 and and I have 2 child(dren) my parents ???

**expected:**
I am 1 and and I have 4 child(dren) my parents 0
I am 2 and and I have 2 child(dren) my parents 1

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


typedef struct parameter {
    unsigned int amount_children;
    int thread_number;
} parameter_t;

#define MAX_CHILDTHREADS 16
#define N_ZERO 4
unsigned int countthreads = 0;
unsigned int divisor = 2;

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
pthread_attr_t attr;



void * tree(void*);

int main(){
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex,NULL);
    //countthreads++;
    parameter_t params = { N_ZERO*divisor, countthreads};
    //pthread_create(&th,&attr,&tree,(void*)&params);
    tree(&params);
    printf("Totalamount of created Threads %d \n", countthreads);

}

void * tree(void * args){
    parameter_t* paramArgs = (parameter_t*) args;
    int N_threads = paramArgs->amount_children / divisor; // anzahl der theoretisch benötogten Threads
    int amount_childthreads = (N_threads <= MAX_CHILDTHREADS) ? N_threads : MAX_CHILDTHREADS;
    pthread_t threads[amount_childthreads];
    printf("I am %d and and I have %d child(dren), my parent is ???\n", paramArgs->thread_number, 
    amount_childthreads);

    parameter_t param[ amount_childthreads ];
    for(int i = 0; i < amount_childthreads; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        int j = ++countthreads;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

        param[i].amount_children = N_threads;
        param[i].thread_number = j;
        pthread_create( threads+i, &attr, &tree, param + i );
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < amount_childthreads; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    printf("I am %d and done\n",paramArgs->thread_number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the POSIX [getppid()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/) function to get your parent process' PID.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).